# Remote JMS Queue Implementation

Tags: jboss, jms

Good Day

I would just like to ask some help / clarification as well since I am new in implementing JMS, I've already been to the following link

"Failed to create session factory"  from client connecting to jboss-as7 hornetq
[HORNETQ-952] When binding AS to 0.0.0.0 remote HornetQ clients fail - JBoss Issue Tracker
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-9393

May I ask how do you do JMS Queue remoting on **JBOss 7.1.1.Final**
I'm using RemoteConnectionFactory in my connection
Do I need to bind my remote(172.45.45.45) jboss server to a specific IP address in order to connect to it remotely? Like passing a –b IPAddress upon starting jboss?
or configuring it on standalone.conf like this
And in remote IP /jboss/bin/standalone.conf (do I really need this?)

```
# set this value so we can send JMS messages from remote clients
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=172.45.45.45”
```

Here is a scenario I wanted to send a JMS message to my Queue in my local laptop, I have a publisher for my queue and on 172.45.45.45 (remote ip) web.war() is deployed in that remote IP and  I have my consumer  configured to this queue

```
   <jms-queue name=“testqueue">
                    <entry name="java:jboss/queue/mss/testqueue"/>
                    <durable>true</durable>
                </jms-queue>
```

I have configured my Jboss application user with the guest role
I have my queue config in standalone.xml(copy of standalone-full.xml)
I have my JMS publisher/consumer

If I have the following config below, sending JMS message remotely is working fine. Without that I’m getting a error=2 cannot connect to server(s)

my local etc/hosts config for that IP  (do I really need this?)
    enter code here
    172.45.45.45     ip-172-45-45-45.ec2.internal

remote Jboss server config
And in remote IP /jboss/bin/standalone.conf (do I really need this?)

```
#set this value so we can send JMS messages from remote clients
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=172.45.45.45”
```

BTW i followed this tutorial
http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/remote-jms-client-and-ejb3-mdb-consumer-eclipse-jboss-7-1/

Need help on implementing JMS queue remotely without the following configuration
my local etc/hosts config for that IP  (do I really need this?)
    172.45.45.45     ip-172-45-45-45.ec2.internal

remote Jboss server config
And in remote IP /jboss/bin/standalone.conf (do I really need this?)

```
#set this value so we can send JMS messages from remote clients
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.bind.address=172.45.45.45”
```

Here is the Code snippet for my JMS Publisher

```
private static String username = "testuser";
private static String password = "testpass";
private static String host = "remote://172.45.45.45:4447";


Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
try {
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, host);
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)    context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(username, password);
topic = (Topic) context.lookup("jms/topic/testTopic");
System.out.println("Connected to JMS");
connection.start();
```

Sample Code snippet from my Consumer

```
/**
* Message-Driven Bean implementation class for: MDBSample- This is for Consume the Queue
*/
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName =  "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/queue/test"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
public class MessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public MessageConsumer() {

}

/**
 * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
 */
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    try {
     ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) message;
     JMSMessage jmsMessage = (JMSMessage) msg.getObject();
        System.out.println("Received message is ==========> " + jmsMessage.getAction());
    } catch (JMSException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Any Ideas or suggestion?

Comment: Just to follow up question Do I really need the configuration on my etc/hosts(local computer) and on my standalone.conf(remote jboss)

Comment: Just for future reference to others, I manage to resolve my issue on this, by implementing the connection without the JNDI :) 

from that implementation I dont need to configure my etc/hosts and dont need to bind my address remotely
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/usermanual-2.0.0.beta2/html/using-jms.html

Comment: do you able to `telnet yourIP 4447`